# Oracle ADF. LOV will not populate correctly

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf

I have an ADF page created (11g r2) and I have a column on the page with a list of values its code looks as followed:

```
<af:inputComboboxListOfValues id="nameId"
        popupTitle="Search and Select: #{bindings.Name.hints.label}"
        value="#{bindings.Name.inputValue}"
        label="#{bindings.Name.hints.label}"
        model="#{bindings.Name.listOfValuesModel}"
        required="#{bindings.Name.hints.mandatory}"
        columns="22"
        shortDesc="#{bindings.Name.hints.tooltip}">
    <f:validator binding="#{bindings.Name.validator}"/>
</af:inputComboboxListOfValues>
```

This works correctly when i first open the page, But once i select a different name from the list it duplicates itself and i can never select the first name again. The list gets messed up. Has anyone seen this problem before?

[image: first image]

[image: second]

Answer (score 0):

Open bindings tab and then click on the binding of lov, then in property inspector other>SelectItemValueMode set ListIndex. Like here:
http://withice.blogspot.com/2012/12/list-of-values-doesnt-work-properly.html